# vuejs better way to address component with dynamic template and its relative data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have following question/requirement, if anyone has good idea, please kindly post for discussion
It is for the dynamically rendering for dynamical template and data use component
The scenario is as following:

root vue instance fetch data from backend, say following data returned:

```
[
{
    /* this section will be fed to a component */
    type: 'FirstSub',
    templatestr: '<div> <more-vue-customized-component itsdata="xxx"></more-vue-customized-component>  </div>',
    data: [
        datafordynamicComponent: xxxx
    ]

},
...
{
    /* this section will be fed to a component */
    type: 'lastSub',
    templatestr: '<p> <more-vue-customized-component itsdata="xxx"></more-vue-customized-component>  </p>',
    data: [
        datafordynamicComponent: xxxx
    ]

}
```

]
2. which structure/architecture we can use to render as following composition using above data?

```
<root>
<FirstSub></FirstSub>
...
<lastSub></lastSub>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use async components?

https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Async-Components